# Jquery converting textarea into cell

Tags: jquery

Here,you could see an textarea.Say,i enter some data and if i press enter ,inside text area,it should be converted back to cell.
http://jsfiddle.net/Pjcwf/27/

Comment: what's your problem? please be more specific

Comment: Which cell are you talking about?

Comment: $("textarea.tagme").tagify is not defined in this fiddle - is this function supposed to add the functionality you are hinting at?

Comment: @Mike C:Pls,help me wit this stackoverflow.com/questions/6994645/jquery-tagify-plug-in

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('.tagme').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var t = $(this);
        t.parent().html(t.val());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pjcwf/28/

Comment: @user882583 Because your reference to the tagify library isn't right. I've fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pjcwf/31/

Comment: :when i press spacebar,input data should convert into tag and press enter should change back as td with holding the tag.here it is converting into cell and moving forward.press enter should remove textbox